# C# 'Version' of a double pointer? (i.e. BYTE **variable)

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I know C# doesn't have pointers, so how would I 'convert' a double pointer to C#?

I'm dealing with MPEG-TS(transport streams)

```
int ParseTxPkt(BYTE *pTxPkt, BYTE **ppPayload, int &payloadLen, int &pid, 
    int &payload_unit_start_indicator,int &continuity_counter,
    __int64 &pcr,__int64 &offset,bool peek)
```

Referring to the second parameter.  BYTE * goes to byte[], and the &variables go to ref int ...  I believe...?

Comment: How do you convert a single pointer?

Comment: C++:
BYTE *variable
    
C#:
byte[] variable

Comment: @geeoph just out of curiosity why do you want C or equivalent functionality in C#

Comment: I am trying to rewrite C++ code into C#.  One parameter in the C++ function is "BYTE **ppPayload" so I need some way to do that in C#.   That is at least if I can do the same thing using both languages.

Comment: _One parameter in the C++ function is "BYTE **ppPayload"_ - add it to the question, with a sample of how the method is called. You need more than a change of the parameter.

Comment: int ParseTxPkt(BYTE *pTxPkt, BYTE **ppPayload, int &payloadLen, int &pid, int &payload_unit_start_indicator,int &continuity_counter,__int64 &pcr,__int64 &offset,bool peek)

Referring to the second parameter.  BYTE * goes to byte[], and the &variables go to ref int ...  I believe...?

Comment: Your payload could become `byte[,]` or `byte[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

On function parameters you can mark your parameters with `ref` or `out` for one of the starts, use `[]` for the other.

```
private void Foo(ref byte[] likeADoublePointer)
{
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use jagged array, `byte[][]`